# PHP MYSQL RETURN ARRAY IN A FIELD

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little confused how to start this.  I have a table of attribute names and then a table of attribute field names.  As such

```
**Table: attributes**
id
name

**Table: attributes_fields **
id
attrID
fieldname
```

The attrFields can have multiple records attached to a single attr.  I'm trying to get the output something like so.

```
Name    Fields (comma separated field id's)
9       1,3,4,5
```

So far I have this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM attributes 
    LEFT JOIN attributes_fields on attributes.attributeID = attributes_fields.attributeFieldParentID
WHERE attributes.attributeID = 9
```

Which works, but not as I would like it.  I'm looking for one row to be returned.  The above returns all the fields as multiple rows.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Show PHP code, please. Use mysqli , please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function to do this.
This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. The full syntax is as follows:

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])

mysql> SELECT student_name,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(test_score)
    ->     FROM student
    ->     GROUP BY student_name;
```

Or:

```
mysql> SELECT student_name,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
    ->               ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
    ->     FROM student
    ->     GROUP BY student_name;
```

Please check it here: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function%5Fgroup-concat)

Answer (score 1):

I was about to suggest GROUP_CONCAT as well. In your query:

```
SELECT a.id as Name, GROUP_CONCAT( f.id SEPARATOR ',') as Fields 
FROM attributes a
    LEFT JOIN attributes_fields f on a.attributeID = f.attributeFieldParentID
WHERE a.attributeID = 9
```

It should give you the result you're looking for.